# SwiftUI view freezes due to Timer object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

When I try to update a text in SwiftUI view using Timer and `.onReceive(timer)` modifier, view freezes.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation

var globalText: String = "abc"

struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var myText = globalText
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .default)
                     .autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AVContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
            Text(myText)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in myText = globalText }
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct AVContainer : UIViewRepresentable { ... }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are likely recreating your entire app every time it runs timers are usually a bandaid to another issue. Also, globals are generally considered bad practice but they are exceptionally bad practice with SwiftUI. It is simply a pattern that does not work with it.

Comment: UIViewRepresentable is tricky to get right try without that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem with my AR app. In your case, you need to declare and instantiate the view in the ContentView struct, and then create its binding variable in the AVContainer struct. I can't explain why the below approach works, but it definitely works – there's no freezing anymore.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation

var globalText: String = "abc"

struct ContentView : View {    
    @State var yourView = YourView(frame: .zero)
    @State var myText = globalText
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .default)
                     .autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AVContainer(yourView: $yourView).ignoresSafeArea()
            Text(myText)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in myText = globalText }
                .font(.largeTitle)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Restart App") {
                    self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    myText = "..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}    
struct AVContainer : UIViewRepresentable { 
    @Binding var yourView: YourView
    // code here ...
}
```

Comment: It "works" because the ARView is now stored in SwiftUI's State storage instead of being recreated. `UIViewRepresentable` likes to maintain control of the `UIView` that it is rendering though, by doing this you take that control. You may encounter other issues with this setup because of this. Threading, things being out of sync, etc.

Comment: Appreciate your comment and will take it into consideration, thanks!

Comment: Andy thank you very much. everything works great